# Open Peripherals getAllStacks() issue

Tags: lua, computercraft

This is an example of my code

```
inv = peripheral.wrap("right")
var1 = inv.getAllStacks()
var2 = var1[1] --This should set var2 to another table
print(var2[1])
```

When I execute this program on an advanced computer with a diamond chest next to it, with things inside, it prints nothing at all. please help me out with this!

Comment: What does that mean, "on an advanced computer with a diamond chest next to it"? Also, have you run it on a machine and gotten it to print stuff? what makes you think that `var2[1]` is not nil?

Comment: Open Peripherals and computercraft (tags) are mods to the popular game "minecraft" which i was coding in. I am going to post an answer as I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
What the getAllStacks() method does is returns a table full of dictionaries. So, to get the name of the item in stack one, you would do this:

```
chest = peripheral.wrap("right")
chestInv = chest.getAllStacks()
item1 = chestInv[1]
print(item1["name"]) --Because name is the term and the value is the name of the item.
```

this above code will print the name of the item in the first slot of chest.

Answer (score 0):

Use an addon (AddonCCPeripherals) and connect your chest with the Computer (with the proxy)! now you have to code:

```
chest = peripheral.wrap("diamond_0")
Diamond chest: "diamond_0"
Iron chest: "iron_0"
```

(sorry if there some Errors in my text, im from Germany [but the code is right])